# query builder Codeigniter4 - getResultArray retornando bool

Tags: codeigniter-3

Boa tarde pessoal.

Voltei a proggramar com Codeigniter 4. Me deparei com esse problema ao fazer o Join em 3 tabelas.

Produto linha_produto tipo_produto

A tabela produto tem os ids da linha e do tipo de produto

No meu Model esta com esta consulta (usando o build)) `

$builder = $this->db->table('produto');
$builder->select(''.
'produto.id_produto,'.
'produto.nome_produto,'.
'linha_produto.id_linha,'.
'linha_produto.nome_linha'.
'tipo_produto.id_tipo_produto,'.
'tipo_produto.nome_tipo_produto');

```
    $builder->from('linha_produto,tipo_produto');
    
    $builder->join('linha_produto','produto.id_linha_produto = linha_produto.id_linha');
    $builder->join('tipo_produto','produto.id_tipo_produto = tipo_produto.id_tipo_produto');
    
    $query = $builder->get();
    
    
    return $query->getResultArray();
```

` No meu Controller estou exibindo (para teste) assim:

`

$teste = $this->produtoModel->GetProdutoLinhaTipo();
foreach($teste as $iter){
echo $iter['id_produto'];
echo $iter['nome_linha'];
}
`

Quando retiro o JOIN referente a tabela de tipo_produto, a consulta me retorna os dados e printa tudo na tela, mas quando incluo o JOIN do tipo_produto nao vai. Apresenta este erro:

Call to a member function getResultArray() on bool

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda!

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver a minha duvida.

Era coisa idiota! Obrigado a quem negativou a pergunta. Me forçou a pesquisar e ler melhor o manual!

Isso resolve o problema:

```
$builder = $this->db->table('produto p');
    $builder->join('linha_produto lp', 'p.id_linha_produto = lp.id_linha');
    $builder->join('tipo_produto tp', 'p.id_tipo_produto_produto = tp.id_tipo_produto');
    
    $query = $builder->get();
    return $query->getResultArray();
```